# Can I add more than 1 millions strings in List?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

According to :http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/737799/IntelliSense-TextBox-in-Csharp

Is this good or bad?

If i want to add **EVERY ENGLISH WORDS** on it.

(If anyone have a good ways or any methods or good suggest I can use?)

***I am a beginner that learns for fun . So, try not to give an answer that is to complicated or too details... ok :)***

Take a look at both of the images down here:

[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWOvx.jpg)

Comment: Of course you can add a million strings to a list. Can you be more specific with the actual issue you're having?

Comment: You can, but should you? it would make more sense to use a database. Plus, think of the utility - some user enters a fragment of a word, and gets 100,000 possible matches. What possible use is that?

Comment: Hi Rob, have you view my image 1 yet? I show the image to some others site says that I did is wrong. Can you check the "IMAGE 1" see if can works?Thanks

Comment: @user1666620 is it something like sql database?

Comment: @WanFai You are creating that list every time they press a key. So that by itself is a huge problem. There's quite a few things you'll need to fix and optimise, but you should post your *code*, not a screenshot of your code. Also, you need a specific problem, rather than saying "Can I do this"? Because the answer is that is "try it". The example code you've linked isn't really a good example to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can! But it will a very tedious work. So good luck! Have fun entering all those words in an array!

No, I'm just kidding. There are better ways to do this.

Instead of entering all English words into an array in code, why not enter them in a text file? When you want to use it, just create a stream and plug it into the file.

I think what you want to create is something similar to IntelliSense. I think you don't want to display *all* of the English words to the user. You just want to display words based on what the user has typed, don't you? Then, when you read the file, just skip those words that do not contain what the user has typed. And for those words that contain the user's text, add them to an array!

For example, if I type "cu", you don't give me "cat" but you will give me "cut".

In addition, make this an asynchronous operation. This is probably going to take a long time to read that file with a million words in it. So yeah, make use of `async/await`.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible yes, is it a good idea? Generally no.
In most cases it will make your application run very slowly which is why I recommend Threading for these types of task.
[Threading C# MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)